# How to add value before create using gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have this `post.go` model

```
package models

type Post struct {
    Id             uint   `json:"ID"`
    Name           string   `json:"Name"`
    Message        string `gorm:"type:text; index" json:"Message"`
    Status         string `gorm:"type:varchar(255); index" json:"Status"`
    Desc           string `gorm:"type:text; index" json:"Desc"`
}

func (p *Post) BeforeCreate() (err error) {
    p.Status = "todo"
    return nil
}
```

I need when I create any record by default put the status into the `todo` value

in my controller:

```
config.DB.Model(&models.Post{}).Create(&posts)
```

The result is I got a null value in status in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeforeCreate` interface signature is incorrect it should be `BeforeCreate(*gorm.DB) error`

```
func (p *Post) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    p.Status = "todo"
    return nil
}
```

Another way would be to add [`default-values`](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values) to the post struct

```golang
type Post struct {
    Id             uint   `json:"ID"`
    Name           string `json:"Name"`
    Message        string `gorm:"type:text; index" json:"Message"`
    Status         string `gorm:"type:varchar(255); index; default: todo" json:"Status"`
    Desc           string `gorm:"type:text; index" json:"Desc"`
}
```

**Output:**

```
db.Create(&Post{}) // INSERT INTO `posts` (`name`,`message`,`status`,`desc`) VALUES ("","","todo","") RETURNING `id`
```

Comment: What about `BeforeCreate` hook! what is the problem!

Comment: @kepemo2494 with `BeforeCreate` you are not implement the interface signature correctly, it should be `BeforeCreate(*gorm.DB) error`